# How to delete user related data when deleting the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm working on a ROR application which uses ActiveAdmin. I want to achieve something like this - *When we delete a user the devices registered by him should also get delete.*

The code of batch action is as follows -

```
batch_action :destroy, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete these users?", do |ids|
   SearchableUser.where(id: ids).destroy_all
   redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Successfully destroyed users"
   end
```

I want to add a command here in batch action which first delete the devices register by that user and then delete the user.

NOTE: Want to achieve this without affecting the model.

Is there any way to achieve this? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to specify a `dependent: :destroy` or `dependent: :delete_all` on the model. If that's not something you can do, you could theoretically achieve the same through something like this (untested):

```
batch_action :destroy, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete these users?", do |ids|
   Children.where(parent_id: ids).destroy_all
   Parent.where(id: ids).destroy_all
   redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Successfully destroyed users"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the devices are a separate class and the dependency has been declared in the User model, you can set `dependent: destroy` to delete all dependent entries.

```
class Parent
  has_many :children, dependent: destroy
end
```

Comment: Can we achieve this without affecting the model?

Comment: @Geek, affecting the model how?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
  #or 
  has_many :children, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

with :destroy ==>  delete the objects by calling destroy method.(it run the call backs of its children in deleting)

but :delete_all ==> All associated objects are destroyed immediately without calling callbacks.